# How to properly display newlines in an R string?

Tags: r

Here is some R code that shows newlines in a string become `\n`.

```
> foo <- "foo
+ bar"
> foo
[1] "foo\nbar"
> print(foo)
[1] "foo\nbar"
```

How can I get the printed output to show the newlines?  That is:

```
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cat function to print it the way you are asking.

`cat(foo)`

from `?cat()` you should keep in mind:

> No linefeeds are output unless explicitly requested by "\n" or if generated by filling (if argument fill is TRUE or numeric).